# how do I include a Promise polyfill in a Cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, promise, cordova-plugins

I'm testing a Cordova plugin (https://github.com/mutualmobile/cordova-bluetoothle/blob/master/src/www/bluetoothle.js) that uses the Javascript Promise API. The plugin will be used in an Android app which has a webview that runs using Chrome 30. This version of Chrome is relatively old and doesn't natively support the Promise API. Rather than use Crosswalk I want to include the Promise API as a polyfill using code from promisejs.org (https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-6.1.0.js). Can anyone advise on how I include the polyfill into the plugin linked to above? I've tried adding the following to `plugin.xml` file but can't seem to work out how to reference it in `bluetoothle.js`

```
<js-module src="www/promise-6.1.0.js" name="Promise">
    <clobbers target="promise"/>
</js-module>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A promise polyfill should be around 100 LoC, you can probably just copy paste the content.

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Many thanks for your suggestion. Had tried this already using a browserify version of the promisejs library and it hadn't worked. After your suggestion I gave it another shot pasting the code from promise-6.1.0.js file I linked to above instead and it's now working, thanks! I'm going to leave the question open for a while as I'd like to know if there's a cleaner way of doing it. Cheers.

Comment: Hey @ChristopherDuke, can you share the solution build as Promise wrapper for bluetoothle cordova plugin, I'm currently solving similar problem...

Comment: Hi @Zbysek-KenticoSoftware, been a while since I used this but I think all I did to get it working was copy the code from promise-6.1.0.js and paste it into the top of bluetoothle.js. Will have a dig around and see if I can find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promisejs.org polyfill is packed in an unconventional way, you could use the [taylorhakes/promise-polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) that is using a simple module.exports at the end of the module.

In order to preserve the native Promise just alter the export line from:

```
module.exports = Promise;
```

to:

```
module.exports = root.Promise || Promise;
```

and add this to your config.xml

```xml
<js-module name="Promise" src="www/Promise.js">
    <clobbers target="Promise" />
</js-module>
```